# this.props is not a function redux from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components

Hi I am having an issue calling an action in a child component.

However, I can run the CompanyForm component by itself and it'll work, but when treated as a child component, I run into an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.createCompany is not a function

Companies.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CompanyForm/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

CompanyForm.js

```
import { createCompany } from "../../actions/companyAction";
export class CompanyForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        companyName: '',
        street1: '',
        street2: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        zipcode: ''
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}


handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const company = {
        ...
    };
    console.log(company);
    this.props.createCompany(company)

}
}
export default connect(null, { createCompany })(CompanyForm);
```

companyActions.js

```
export const createCompany = (companyData) => dispatch => {
console.log('CREATE_COMPANY: ', companyData);
fetch('api/Company/Create', {
    ...
)};
```

Comment: @Kabbany: whoops you are right. I got the method/props switched in my head.

Comment: I think you have a typo in you filenames. Is it `companyActions.js` or `companyAction.js` ?

Comment: @Kabbany the file is definitely named companyAction.js. It's really a strange error... Also, if I have `CompanyForm.propTypes = {
    createCompany: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};` enabled

Then I get a warning in `<CompanyForm />` stating `does not have required attribute createCompany`

Comment: @Kabbany Ok...So I figured out how to fix my issue, but I don't think it is the right way...?
`<CompanyForm createCompany={this.props.createCompany}/>` and in my Companies Component, I called `export default connect(null, {createCompany})(Companies);`

Is there a better way to do this? it seems a bit redundant

Comment: Can you provide code for how you are calling `handleSubmit` ?

Comment: @Kabbany `render() { <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>...</form>}`

Comment: @GWFreak01 How are you importing `CompanyForm` in the other file ?

Comment: @Kabbany `import { CompanyForm } from "../companyForm/CompanyForm";` I just noticed this, but is there a huge difference between having and not having the `{ }`?

EDIT: OOHHHHHH MAMA!!! I removed the {} around my imports and it started working! Thanks for that help!

Answer (score 0):

import child components without curly braces into the parent component
i.e.

```
import CompanyForm from '../component/companyForm/CompanyForm';
```

NOT

```
import { CompanyForm } from '../component/companyForm/CompanyForm';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting both the component and the connected component you have to make sure you are importing the right one. The right one in this case is the connected component.